# Pointers and Referencing

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Here is the problem. i am trying to create a memory diagram and i understand everything up until b++ because when that code is executed it changes the value of val from 10 to 4. What is the reason for that?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void mem(int*& a, int* b){
    a --;
    b++;
    a = new int[3];
    a[0] = 3;
    a[1] = *b;
    a[2] = ++(*b);
}
int main()
{
    int data[] = {2, 4, 6, 8};
    int *ptrA = data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
        (*ptrA)++;
        ptrA++;
    }
    int val = 10;
    mem(ptrA, &val);
}
```

Comment: Is the ampersand sign in 'void mem(int*& a, int* b)' intentional?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `b` is a pointer to an integer, and `b++` asks the pointer to increment (i.e., point to the next available integer) in the same manner as `ptrA++`. The difference, however, is that `ptrA` points to the beginning of an array; we still own the memory for the next available integer, so everything is okay. For `b`, it points to a single integer; incrementing it and trying to use it afterwards leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`b++;` is incrementing the address that `b` holds to be one `int` after the `int` address it had.

After this any use of the variable is undefined as we now point to some unspecified memory.